# How to enable Facebook PLAY NOW button

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I recently published a game on Facebook games and got approved but when check the game, I do not have the "PLAY NOW" button. All I have is "SEND TO MOBILE".

I am wondering what I missed and why mine is not showing the "PLAY NOW" button like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What exactly users get shown, depends on the device they are using, and the app settings.

Canvas is not available on mobile, so users on those platforms will get send to the appropriate app store instead, if your app is available for those.

Comment: Hi, this is just on a desktop web browser. Other games show the play now button so you can play the game, so I am wondering if i have to convert my game to HTML5 and store it somewhere and then reference it on facebook as canvas?

Comment: Well what platforms is your game configured for? Pretty sure you need canvas if you want the play now button to show up on desktop.